# How to restrict user to submit form if he doesnot select value from select Box-PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am working on a project where admin have rights to add new users.

In ADD NEW USER form i have a select BOX of Designation which is populated from database . i want to know if user not select any designation from select options it will give error please select designation or some thing like this.
Here is my code:

```
<select class="form-control" name="designation" id="designation" style="color:  black;" required>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['designation_id']; ?>">Please Select designation</option>
    <?php
    $sel_cus = "select designation_name ,designation_id from designation ";
    $res_cus = mysqli_query($connection, $sel_cus);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res_cus)) { ?>

        <option value="<?php echo $row['designation_id ']; ?>"><?php echo $row['designation_name']; ?></option>

    <?php
}
?>
</select>
```

If selected index of select box is 0 which is [Please Select designation] it will give error please select designation from list.
Need kind guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing `$row` variable before it even exist in the following statement,

```
<option value="<?php echo $row['designation_id']; ?>">Please Select designation</option>
```

please replace this statement with following,

```
<option value="">Please Select designation</option>
```

value should be blank for the first option of select to work with required attribute.

Refer to this [specification](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/the-select-element.html#the-select-element)

And if you dont want the error to appear just remove the `required` attribute from the select element.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this approach.

```
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    <select class="form-control" name="designation" id="designation" style="color:  black;" required>
        <option value="0">Please Select designation</option>
        <option value="1">designation 1</option>
        <option value="2">designation 2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<script>
    function validateForm(){
        var e = document.getElementById('designation');
        var selectedDesig = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        if(selectedDesig == 0){
            alert('Please Select designation');
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
```